# How To customize Copy To clipboard button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, clipboard

Here is some code snippet that created for a cross-browser copy-to-clipboard ability. But the problem is that I can't able to customize the copy button as it is created in javascript. can anyone help?

Basically, I need to add this copy to clipboard button to a code box

```js
function selectElementContents(el) {
    // Copy textarea, pre, div, etc.
    if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        // Internet Explorer
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.select();
        textRange.execCommand("Copy");
    }
    else if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
        // Non-Internet Explorer
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
        try {
            var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
            var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
            console.log('Copy command was ' + msg);
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
        }
    }
} // end function selectElementContents(el)

function make_copy_button(el) {
    var copy_btn = document.createElement('input');
    copy_btn.type = "button";
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(copy_btn, el.nextSibling);
    copy_btn.onclick = function() {
        selectElementContents(el);
    };

    if (document.queryCommandSupported("copy") || parseInt(navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrom(e|ium)\/([0-9]+)\./)[2]) >= 42) {
        // Copy works with Internet Explorer 4+, Chrome 42+, Firefox 41+, Opera 29+
        copy_btn.value = "Copy to Clipboard";
    }
    else {
        // Select only for Safari and older Chrome, Firefox and Opera
        copy_btn.value = "Select All (then press Ctrl + C to Copy)";
    }
}
/* Note: document.queryCommandSupported("copy") should return "true" on browsers that support copy,
    but there was a bug in Chrome versions 42 to 47 that makes it return "false".  So in those
    versions of Chrome feature detection does not work!
    See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=476508
*/

make_copy_button(document.getElementById("markup"));
```

```html
<pre id="markup">
  Text that can be copied or selected with cross browser support.
</pre>
```

Comment: You can customise the button in anyway you like, through JS. It's accessible via the `copy_btn` variable. Without you saying ***what*** customisation you're looking to make, we cannot offer any useful help

Comment: See this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Just I want to locate the button to a specific position, changing its color, fonts etc basically i want to add this button in one corner of the code box

Comment: In which case put a class on it as @Celsiuss suggested and style that class using CSS as normal.

Comment: Can't find a way to customize the button can you help a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can style it however you like by defining the button with HTML and adding a `click` event listener:

```js
function selectElementContents(el) {
    // Copy textarea, pre, div, etc.
    if (document.body.createTextRange) {
        // Internet Explorer
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.select();
        textRange.execCommand("Copy");
    }
    else if (window.getSelection && document.createRange) {
        // Non-Internet Explorer
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
        try {
            var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
            var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
            console.log('Copy command was ' + msg);
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log('Oops, unable to copy');
        }
    }
} // end function selectElementContents(el)
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
  selectElementContents(document.getElementById("markup"));
})
```

```css
button{
width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<pre id="markup">
  Text that can be copied or selected with cross browser support.
</pre>
<button><i class="material-icons">content_copy</i></button>
```

Comment: this code is not working for blogger due to && entities and if i used <script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
Javascript code here
// ]]>
</script> this form then also not working and help